# functionality of c argument in matplotlib's scatter() function for a random walk

Tags: python, matplotlib, arguments, scatter

I am having trouble distinguishing the differences when I pass different lists to scatter() c argument parameter.

For a random walk session of say 10 steps, I have a list of x coordinates (x_values), a list of y coordinates (y_values), and a list of numbers from 0-9 (point_numbers). The x_values and y_values list have random numbers generated for them. When I pass x_values to the c argument my graphs color in from white to dark blue, from left to right. When I pass y_values, the graph colors in from bottom to top. However, when I pass the point_numbers list, the graph is colored in from the starting point in the random walk, followed by the next point being a little darker, and on and on until it reaches the last point in the walk where it is the darkest.

```
plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, c=x_values, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, s=15)
```

The above colors from left to right.

```
plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, c=y_values, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, s=15)
```

The above colors in from bottom to top.

```
plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, c=point_numbers, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, s=15)
```

And finally the above colors the graph in from first point in the walk, to the next, and so on.

What I want to know is what is going on behind the scenes that allows matplotlib to color in from left to right and bottom to top with x_values and y_values respectively? Also, most importantly, what is going on when I pass a list of numbers (point_numbers), which strictly only has the numbers 0-9, to c and it colors in the walk step by step as opposed to what it does with x_values and y_values?

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't colorize from left to right or bottom to top. It simply takes the value in the list you supply to `c` and takes the color from the colormap that corresponds to the fraction of that value normalized between the minimum and maximum of all list values.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes a ton more sense, have a good evening!